# Generating an auth token for connecting to firebase from node

Tags: node.js, firebase, token, service-accounts

With the number of recent changes released for Firebase it's becoming hard to understand how things work now. Does anyon know how to generate a simple token for my node js back-end to be able to make http calls to a firebase db?

I need to use http calls and not have the connection be persisted using the firebase npm module because I need to run automated tests and I can't find a way to close the connection cleanly (and don't want to use process.exit()).

I already have a json service account key from my GCP AIM and that's what the updated firebase documentation seems to point to using but I can't find a way to use it (examples) or generate a token with it.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `firebase-cli` [docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) indicate `login:ci` will "Generate an authentication token for use in non-interactive environments."

Is that what you need?